# Есть ли другой способ избежать дублирования кода в методах, помимо добавления прослойки базовым классом? (есть ли "миксины" для методов?)

Tags: flutter, dart

Хотелось бы избежать дублирования кода в таких случаях (см. повторяемый паттерн кода в теле методов `fetchFoo` и `fetchBar`):

```
class MyUglyApiClient extends GetConnect {
  Object?     _lastError;
  StackTrace? _lastErrorStacktrace;
  Foo foo = Foo();
  Bar bar = Bar();
  /* ..всякие геттеры приватных свойств вида `lastError`, и прочие.. */

  Future<bool> fetchFoo() async {
    final res = await getRequest('/foo/', operation: 'Foo op');
    if ((lastError != null) || (res == null)) return false;
    try {
      foo = Foo.fromJson(res);
      return (Foo.items.length > 0);
    } catch (err, st) {
      _lastError = err;
      _lastErrorStacktrace = st;
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> fetchBar() async {
    final res = await getRequest('/bar/', operation: 'Bar op');
    if ((lastError != null) || (res == null)) return false;
    try {
      /* ..тут всякие предварительные проверки `res`.. */
      bar = Bar.fromJson(res);
      /* ..тут доп. действия с `bar`.. */
      return (bar.count > 0);
    } catch (err, st) {
      _lastError = err;
      _lastErrorStacktrace = st;
      return false;
    }
  }

  /* ..вспомогательные методы, типа `getRequest`, `postRequest` и прочие..
}
```

Тут важно разделение "уровней" проверки ошибок, то есть реализация `getRequest` уже включает в себе обработку ошибок на уровне сети/доступа (проверки HTTP-кода и формата ответа, создание специфичных `Error`'ов), а вот эти два метода обрабатывают ошибки уже на уровне полученных данных (содержания серверного ответа) - такое разделение важно сохранить.

---

Поэтому, пока что вижу здесь только вариант объявления общего метода с коллбэками, типа

```
Future<bool> fetchGenericData(String url, { String operation, ResponseHandler onRes, DataParser? parser }) {
  final res = await getRequest(url, operation: operation);
  if ((lastError != null) || (res == null)) return false;
  try {
    bool isResDataOk = onRes(res);
    return (isResDataOk && (parser == null) ? parser(res) : isResDataOk;
  } catch (err, st) {
    _lastError = err;
    _lastErrorStacktrace = st;
    return false;
}
```

, но в таком подходе не нравится то что точки взаимодействия с данными "прибиты гвоздями" к реализации... то есть, такой общий метод придется регулярно рефакторить по мере добавления новой бизнеслогики, и этого конечно желательно избежать.
Еще можно ввести базовый класс "обработчик данных", то есть спрятав `try..catch` логику в промежуточный слой абстракции, но создание такого класса воспринимается антипаттерном (имхо, много слоев и ветвистые классовые зависимости == переусложнение).

Идеальным решением был бы некий метод-"миксин" с общим `try..catch`, который я бы примешивал к методам (`fetchFoo`,  `fetchBar`, и последующим), оставив в них только бизнеслогику работы с уже успешно сфетченными данными... но не получается сообразить, как при этом и работать с данными внутри "общего" `try..catch` присваивая данные значениям свойств экземпляра `MyUglyApiClient`, и при этом обойтись без прописывания множества коллбэков. Такое возможно как-то реализовать в Dart, *без* внесения дополнительных базовых классов?

Comment: Миксин на метод нет, как и перегрузки методов. У вас проблем в том что метод имеет слишком много ответственности. Я думаю вашу проблему можно решить через ООП, делегировав часть работы в класс (а там есть и наследование и миксины).

Comment: Также мне показался очень странным ваш способ кеширования запросов. Вы точно хотите так делать?

Comment: @MiT, понял, спасибо. Решение через "наращивание абстракции" самое очевидное, но Dart мощный язык, и я надеялся на существование какого-то трюка :) Про _«способ кеширования запросов»_ - в данном случае, это нормально: данный код отвечает за данные которые фетчатся только при подключении к серверу, а затем используются повсеместно в приложении на протяжении всей его жизни (они инжектятся как "сервис" в терминах GetX, то есть как permanent провайдер). За динамические данные отвечают другие классы, которые используют Bindings и автодиспозятся (я еще и явно присваиваю `null` св-вам при разрушении)

Comment: Думаю тут подойдёт [шаблонный метод](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/template-method) или даже [цепочка обязанностей](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility), а возможно и комбинация обеих.